# how to publish/access C# desktop app via browser?

Tags: c#, web-applications, virtualization

I have a desktop application developed in c# and i want my clients to access my application via a web browser without any other software installation, how i can accomplish this?

I have tried Citrix XenApp, but it requires to install citrix receiver at client end to access the app.
Do i need to redevelop my application as a web app?

Comment: Hey Nikhil, welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you'd like your desktop C# app to host an embedded web server, there are several options available, depending on which version of .NET your app is running under. There are a few lightweight HTTP servers available which can be hosted within your application.

If your dotnet version allows, I would recommend hosting an Asp.Net Core server instance within your app.